Enforce tuple in object is subset of another tuple in object with TypeScript?
I have a function that accepts an object with query arguments. A simplified example of query args is below. I want to ensure any values in sortBy are present in fields. I can check this at runtime but I am wondering if it is possible to do this with TypeScript.
const validQueryArgs = {
  fields: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const,
  sortBy: ['a'] as const
};

const invalidQueryArgs = {
  fields: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const,
  sortBy: ['d'] as const // ts error here would be great :) 
};


I know you can do something along the lines of this (Matt Pocock has a youtube short about this):
function createQueryArgs<T>({sortBy, fields}: { sortBy: NoInfer<T>, fields: T[] }): {fields: T[], sortBy: T } { 
    return {
      fields,
      sortBy
    }
}

const someArgs = createQueryArgs({
    sortBy: "c", // error here :thumbs-up:
    fields: ["a", "b"] as const
})

Is there any way I can do this without using a pass-through function?
I tried going down a conditional types road but hit a dead-end pretty quickly.
type CheckQueryArgs<T> = T extends { fields: infer Fields, sortBy: infer SortBy } ?
  SortBy extends Fields ?
  true :
  never :
  never

type CheckInvalid = CheckQueryArgs<typeof invalidQueryArgs> // never :thumbs-up:

type CheckValid = CheckQueryArgs<typeof validQueryArgs> // never :thumbs-down:

 TypeScript playground
Thank you!

Are you just looking for a CheckQueryArgs type that works? If so, does this answer your question? https://tsplay.dev/mqg52w If so, I can write up an answer describing how that works.

Just by curiosity, why don't you want to use an identity, "pass-through", function?

@Blackhole I don't think it's that unusual to prefer a purely compile-time solution? If this is for the browser that's just more code to ship over the wire....

@JaredSmith True, true. Hopefully, one day, we'll have #7481, to get compile-time solution without compromising readability.

@Blackhole I am more just curious if it's possible to do it without the pass-through function.

@AlexWayne Thank you for the example! I was trying to start with a conditional type and somehow evolve that into a type I could use with an object and have that type check the fields and sortBy members.

A type cannot describe a relationship without a specific type being used in that relationship.
That means that while this works:
type TestA<T extends string[]>{ items: T, item: T[number] }

You need to be able to satisfy T in order to use the type. So you can't do this:
const objA: TestA = { items: [1,2,3], item: 2 } // wont work

Using function is one way to provide that inference point that can provide a type for T.

But if you want a type to check one of these objects, you can do that. Your attempt:
type CheckQueryArgs<T> = T extends { fields: infer Fields, sortBy: infer SortBy } ?
  SortBy extends Fields ?
  true :
  never :
  never

failed because Fields is inferred as readonly ["a", "b", "c"] and SortBy is inferred as readonly ["c"]. Neither of these types extend the other, because they are tuples with different numbers of members, so they can't be assigned to each other.
You need to index those types by number to get the possible values in that tuple as a union. Then one can extend the other.

Putting all that together, you can do something like this:
type CheckQueryArgs<T extends QueryArgs> =
  T['sortBy'][number] extends T['fields'][number]
    ? T
    : never

type CheckInvalid = CheckQueryArgs<{ fields: ['a', 'b'], sortBy: ['c'] }>
// never

type CheckValid = CheckQueryArgs<{ fields: ['a', 'b'], sortBy: ['a'] }>
// { fields: ['a', 'b'], sortBy: ['a'] }

See playground

Using a function may be the best option though.
